# How to prevent lines drawn with linerenderer from being occluded by other 3d objects in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I draw Line with Line Render for make Grid.
but, if i use this, lines drawn with linerenderer are being occluded depending on the position of the 3d object.
how do i fix it?

Comment: This can be accomplished by using two cameras, one set to draw the entirety of the scene, the other set to draw only the line renderer grid (using layer masks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by writing a custom shader for LineRenderer's material. Simply setting 'ZTest Always' in a shader pass or subshader will make ztest always succeed. Below is an example shader, you should write a version for your project's rendering pipeline.

```
Shader "Custom/LineShader" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Opaque"}
        Pass {
            ZTest Always
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };
            float4 _Color;
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.color = v.color;
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }
            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * i.color;
                return col * _Color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshots]

Comment: It worked well enough for my project. thank you